# How can I allow multiple methods to run at the same time, while certain other methods are not running?

Tags: java, concurrency

Sorry about the wording of the title, haven't explained it well. If someone could edit it that would be nice :)

I have four methods, accessing shared state. Currently they are not thread safe.
The shared state is a list. Two of the methods modify the list, and two iterate it. It's possible to simply synchronize all the methods, but this results in reduced performance - it's perfectly safe for the iterating methods to run simultaneously in multiple threads, as long as no modifying methods are running.

A method of locking which allows multiple readers to run, or a single writer is needed.

```
private List<T> list;
public void insert(T t) {// Write shared state
    list.add(t);
}
public void remove(T t) {// Write shared state
    list.remove(t);
}
public void doStuff(T t) {// Read shared state
    // iterate list and do stuff
}
public void doOtherStuff() {// Read shared state
    // iterate list and do stuff
}
```

Comment: Threads are in use here, and I'd love to change the design to make this unnecessary but I can't, as I'm patching someone else's code to make it concurrent and need to keep it as similar as possible to the original design.

Comment: A little more detail might help. Why is it that certain methods can run at the same time and certain ones can't? Is it because of some shared resource or shared state they're accessing?

Comment: Shared state - an array of arraylists, which a and b modify while c and d only iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) matches your needs. Threads `a` and `b` should acquire `write` lock, while threads `c` and `d` should acquire read one

Comment: As far as I can see, exactly what I need! Thanks

Comment: 3 years late update: The library ReadWriteLock doesn't support two-way reentrancy. I ended up creating [this implementation](https://github.com/nallar/TickThreading/blob/master/src/main/java/nallar/tickthreading/util/concurrent/TwoWayReentrantReadWriteLock.java).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Java's `synchronized` keyword. The keyword creates a lock on a certain object, so you can't run something unless the lock is open (and on running it, it calls the lock). In this case, you need two locks, and you have to lock on a certain object, so you could just create two `Object`s and lock on them. What you need is this:

a/b:

```
synchronized(lock1)
{
    synchronized(lock2)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

c:

```
synchronized(lock1)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

d:

```
synchronized(lock2)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

c and d lock on lock1 and lock2 respectively, which don't conflict each other, and so can run concurrently. However, a and b require both locks to be free in order to run, and so cannot be concurrent with any of the other methods.

Comment: This prevents d/c from running concurrently with itself.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you make a new class, c and d will run concurrently with c and d from other instances just fine.

Comment: I should've made the requirements clearer. c and d need to run concurrently in one instance of the class.

Comment: Then the problem is a little trickier. I can't reply now, but I'll come up with a solution a little later.